# How to create tuple of string list

Tags: python

I have one question .
I don't create list or tuple of string list
Example I have list

> ['test1,test2,2020-10-12,None,None',
> "test5,test6,2021-11-24,None,None",
> 'test7,test8,2021-11-24,None,None']

I need tuple for example

> [('test1,test2,2020-10-12,None,None'),
> ("test5,test6,2021-11-24,None,None"),
> ('test7,test8,2021-11-24,None,None')]

Code for create first list is

```
list_t = (','.join((str(value) for key, value in l.items())) for l in r1)
```

Comment: `[(x,) for x in lst]`

Comment: What you have written is a generator and not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your desired output, it looks like you just want to wrap each item in the list in a tuple of length one. The following code accomplishes this:

```py
items = ['test1,test2,2020-10-12,None,None', "test5,test6,2021-11-24,None,None", 'test7,test8,2021-11-24,None,None']
items_wrapped = [(i,) for i in items]
```

However, if you'd like to split the strings into the tuples you can do it like so:

```py
items = ['test1,test2,2020-10-12,None,None', "test5,test6,2021-11-24,None,None", 'test7,test8,2021-11-24,None,None']
items_wrapped = [tuple(i.split(',')) for i in items]
```